# Detect end of a subprocess from many

Tags: python, subprocess

How can I detected that a subprocess was ending at the time, that the other process(es) are still running?

I upload a short code below:, where the first process ends after 5 seconds and

```
import multiprocessing
import os
import time

def process_with_exit_code(exit_code, delay):
    time.sleep(delay)
    return exit_code

def terminate_processes(processes):
    for process in processes:
        process.terminate()
        process.join()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    process1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=process_with_exit_code, args=(22, 5))
    process2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=process_with_exit_code, args=( 0, 7))

    process1.start()
    process2.start()

    try:
        process1.join()
        process2.join()

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        terminate_processes([process1, process2])
        print("Main process received KeyboardInterrupt. All processes terminated.")
```

It is possible to place a loop that iterate at a give interval on the processes and check if one of them already ended.

Is there a better way?